# Saving "master" element in many to one relationship with ebean

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I am having a little issue with Ebean (in the context of Play Framework, Java).
I have elements sharing a one-to-many relationship (BankAccount <- BankingOperation).

I have defined the BankAccount class with, among others, the following fields:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<BankingOperation> operations = new ArrayList<BankingOperation>();
```

For the Banking operation, the corresponding field:

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnore
public BankAccount bankAccount;
```

My issue is that when I try to update the bank account, it deletes the related operations. Here's the code I am using:

```
public static Result saveAccount(Long id)
{
    Form<BankAccount> form = Form.form(BankAccount.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (form.hasErrors() || form.get().id != id) {
        return badRequest();
    }

    form.get().update(id);

    return ok();
}
```

I have the feeling that operations are deleted because they aren't loaded when I do the form().get(), and thus, when synchronizing with the DB, Ebean does what seems to be the best solution to it.

Would anyone have any clue on this issue? Is there another solution that I haven't discovered yet?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have found a (ugly) solution which is adding the following line before doing the update:

```
Ebean.refreshMany(form.get(), "operations");
```

Another solution could be not to build the form the model class but on an another class, forcing me to map each field one by one.